# Trying to create a class that creates a turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a class where I can build a turtle so I can call that multiple times and get a bunch of turtles. I'm not sure exactly how to create a turtle with the `name = turtle.Turtle()`. It gives me an error but doesn't say why.

```
import turtle
class CreateTurtle:

# initialize constructor
def __init__(self, name, color, pensize, shape):
    self.name = name
    self.color = color
    self.pensize = pensize
    self.shape = shape

def make_turtle(self):
    name = turtle.Turtle()
    name.color(self.color)
    name.pensize(self.pensize)
    name.shape(self.shape)
```

Comment: Please include the error message. There are many things wrong with the code you've provided, notably the indentation, but we can't know for sure unless you tell us what the actual error is and provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make many `turtle` from a class of `Turtle`, you should make `class` and call it with input and assign it to your variable. This is the minimal working example:

```py
class Turtle:
    # initialize constructor
    def __init__(self, name, color, pensize, shape):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.pensize = pensize
        self.shape = shape
```

```py
turtles = []
turtles.append(Turtle('a','b','c','d'))
print(turtles[0].name)
```

You can keep appending to store your `turtles` in list or any format you want.

Note:
There is many Q&A about `Python Class` in SO. You just need to search what you actually needs. This question should be marked as duplicate, but I can't find an appropriate link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using a function to create a class instance, and return it.

Now, you probably want to have many Turtle subclasses, each with different "settings" I suppose, so your best bet is to subclass Turtle, and overwrite the class methods, or add new ones. You also need to indent your functions into the class.

You can do this as follows:

```
class BlueTurtle(Turtle):
    #if you want to inherit directly all the methods of Turtle
    def __init__(param1, param2):
        super().__init__(param1, param2)
        #this will inherit all of Turtle's methods, but you have to configure it
        # to be able to pass in all the params that you'll be using
        # and if there are any obligaroty params.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Class by a separate method of creating the turtles.
For example:

```css
class Turtles: 
        def __init__(self):  
            self.create_turtle()
            self.new_turtles = []

        def create_turtle():
            for i in range(3):
                mini = Turtle()
                mini.shape("square")
                mini.color("white")
                self.new_turtles.append(mini)
```

Main File:
**turtles** = Turtles()

So now, in the variable turtles you have 3 turtles.